# Execute shell command inside makefile.am

Tags: autotools, gtkmm, pkg-config

I have the following Makefile.am inside ./src where I need to generate dependencies for a gtkmm application.

```
bin_PROGRAMS = sampleapplication
sampleapplication_SOURCES = exampleapplication.cpp examplewindow.cpp main.cpp
sampleapplication_INCLUDES = ../include/exampleapplication.h ../include/examplewindow.h
sampleapplication_LDADD = $(DEPS_LIBS)

make_flags=`pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
AM_CPPFLAGS = ${make_flags} -I$(top_srcdir)/include
```

However when I run this command all I see echoed to the screen when this command is run is:

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` -I../include   -g -O2 -MT exampleapplication.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/exampleapplication.Tpo -c -o exampleapplication.o exampleapplication.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/buildable.h:29,
```

Which does not expand out the way I want it. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: If you get the flags when generating `Makefile.in`, it will be flags specific to _your_ system, not of the user who later will use the `Makefile.in` on _his_ system.

Comment: What is the correct approach to this then? I am just starting to learn how to write the build system with autotools.

Comment: I would probably have put it in `configure.ac`, especially the check for if gtkmm-3.0 is available or not.

Comment: When doing so I get the following warning when running autoconf.configure.in:23: warning: macro `AM_CPPFLAGS' not found in library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pkg-config` includes useful autoconf macros, which are described on the `man` page. In `configure.ac` use something like:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GTKMM], [gtkmm-3.0])
```

You now have `GTKMM_CFLAGS`, `GTKMM_LIBS` available for substitution in `Makefile.am` files.

Comment: Also described on page 1 of the gtkmm manual.  Doesn't anyone read  manuals anymore? :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can add this, together with a check for gtkmm, in `configure.ac`.

`configure.ac`:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([for gtkmm-3.0])
if pkg-config gtkmm-3.0; then
    AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])
    GTKMM_CPPFLAGS=`pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags`
    GTKMM_LDFLAGS=`pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs-only-other`
    GTKMM_LIBS=`pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs-only-l`
    AC_SUBST(GTKMM_CPPFLAGS)
    AC_SUBST(GTKMM_LDFLAGS)
    AC_SUBST(GTKMM_LIBS)
else
    AC_MSG_RESULT([no])
fi
```

`Makefile.am`:

```
sampleapplication_CPPFLAGS += @GTKMM_CPPFLAGS@
sampleapplication_LDFLAGS  += @GTKMM_LDFLAGS@
sampleapplication_LIBS     += @GTKMM_LIBS@
```